# Input characters not reading correctly

Tags: c, function, if-statement

This should be a simple error. My code is basically reading a user input value and if the value is greater than 0 it will return the value. If not it will print an error and ask for the value again. The only problem is when a new value is input it uses the old false value without error.

```
int menuSize(int s) {
printf(" Please Enter size: ");
scanf("%i", &s);
if (s>0) {
}
else {
    printf(" Invalid Input\n");
    getchar();
    menuSize(s);
}
return s;
}
```

Comment: Since it is recursive you better do something with the return value of `menuSize` recursive call (like assigning it to s and returning it). Also I don't see a point of passing `s` as parameter. And generally, recursion is not the right technique to use here. Use a loop instead.

Comment: `scanf()` without checking return value... not that much of a problem here as `s` is the function's argument, but usually that is undefined behaviour waiting to happen, as a local `s` won't be initialized if the user did input something other than a string. Possibly also the cause of your problem here. *You don't know*.

Answer (score 1):

If the input is invalid, the function makes a recursive call to itself but doesn't do anything with the return value of the recursive call.  That means the invalid value that was read in the current invocation is what will be returned.

Change the function to return the value of the recursive call.  Also, get rid of the parameter to the function since it isn't used and make `s` local.  You should also initialize `s` to some known value and check the return value of `scanf` in case nothing gets read.

```
int menuSize(void) 
{
    int s = -1;
    printf(" Please Enter size: ");
    int rval = scanf("%i", &s);
    if (rval == 1 && s>0) {
        return s;
    } else {
        printf(" Invalid Input\n");
        getchar();
        return menuSize();
    }
}
```

Comment: `getchar();` does not make sense when `rval == 1 && s<=0`. Perhaps  `if (rval == 0) getchar();`?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica OP stated that they expect a value greater than 0 to be entered, so no value read or a value <= 0 is invalid.

Comment: OP's code has `else {` thus input when `s<=0` need to be handled.  Always using `getchar();` eats into the next input.  IMO,  `getchar();` should only happen when no conversion occurred.  Input like `"-123-456"` should be rejected.  This answer will return that as 456.

Comment: Might want to break recursion on `EOF`.